# Profiling project classes alone using asm jars

Tags: java, profiler

I'm new to profiling.I'm using ASM to create a profiler. the profiler when run gives the class name of jar's included also. But i need details of my project classes only. I got the code from

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jip/#icomments

Comment: Creating a useful profile isn't easy.  VisualVM took a lot of work by experienced developers and I find it almost useless. ;)

Comment: How to create a filter for the classes that to be transformed using the profiler ?... I need a link or tutorial for it

Comment: I would start with the tutorials for the ASM library http://asm.ow2.org/

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a filter for the classes you want to transform on your own.

Just check e.g. if the class name starts with "com/yourcompany/" and leave all other classes alone.

Since you write a profiler, you seem to have a created an agent. The transform method of this agent also passes a ClassLoader with the class data. I am not sure, but maybe you can use this property to filter, too, or check the classloader for the origin of the resource if this is possible.

Comment: Thanks Daniel have u got any link for the filtering the classloader

Comment: Just check for yourself if there is a different ClassLoader for classes loaded from the jars vs. classes loaded directly. You could also just use the getResource() function on the classloader which will return a URL, and from the URL you can see if the class was loaded from a jar. Just play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried VisualVM but its not very useful for high performance applications as its written entirely in Java nd not very efficient. (i.e. if its less efficient than the application its monitoring, you see VisualVM as the biggest consumer of CPU or memory)

VisualVM uses the approach you are attempting. ;)

I use YourKit and find this is useful for common problems, and this may be enough for you.  It has the option of turning profiling on and off in from the code to only include certain sections of code.  This is more efficient because all the profiling work is done in a native agent so it doesn't use any heap of its own, and doesn't slow down the application much.

When Yourkit is not enough for low latency programming, I write bespoke performance tests and have the application time itself at key stages in the application which I log as efficiently as possible.  This approach is light weight enough it can be used in a running system and allows you to see what is happening in a production system.